# QLineEdit with QValidator: React to editing finished regardless of input validity?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qvalidator

`QLineEdit` has a signal `QLineEdit::editingFinished` that gets emitted when the user finished editing, for example by pressing enter. However if a validator or an input mask was set, then `editingFinished` only gets emitted if the input is valid.

But how can I react to the user finishing the editing regardless of the validity of the input? Do I have to manually check for enter, return, the widget losing focus, etc. ?

The reason for this: I wanted to create a custom widget for editing numbers using a `QDoubleValidator`. When the user finishes editing and the input is invalid (wrong range, empty text, ...) I want to reset it to some valid default value. Something like this:

```
class NumberEdit: public QLineEdit
{
public:
    NumberEdit(double min, double max)
    {
        setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(min, max, 10));
        setText(QString::number(min));

        connect(this, /* this is the problem */, [this, min]() {
            if(!hasAcceptableInput())
                setText(QString::number(min));    // Reset to valid number
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you really need to subclass `QLineEdit`.

The *clean* way to change a `QLineEdit` value when it does not have an [`Acceptable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#State-enum) input, is to override `QValidator` and provide an implementation for [`fixup()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#fixup). From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#details):

> `fixup()` is provided for validators that can repair some user errors.
>   The default implementation does nothing. `QLineEdit`, for example, will
>   call `fixup()` if the user presses Enter (or Return) and the content is
>   not currently valid. This allows the `fixup()` function the opportunity
>   of performing some magic to make an `Invalid` string `Acceptable`.

Since you are using [`QDoubleValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html), you can subclass it and provide an implementation for `fixup()`, as it does not have one, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html#details).

The class should look something like this:

```
class MyDoubleValidator : public QDoubleValidator{
public:
    explicit MyDoubleValidator(QObject* parent= nullptr)
        :QDoubleValidator(parent){}
    MyDoubleValidator(double bottom, double top, int decimals, QObject* parent=nullptr)
        :QDoubleValidator(bottom, top, decimals, parent){}

    virtual void fixup(QString& input)const override{
        input= QString::number(bottom(), 'f', decimals());
    }
};
```

That way, you can just use your validator with any `QLineEdit` like this:

```
lineEdit->setValidator(new MyDoubleValidator(100, 200, 2, lineEdit));
```

Note that, this way `lineEdit` will emit [`editingFinished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) after every edit. Because even if the contents of `QLineEdit` were not `Acceptable`, our `fixup()` implementation will always *fix* the contents to be `Acceptable`.

Comment: "... will emit editingFinished() after every edit" --- Did you mean every time the user finish editing (by pressing <Enter> or changing the focus) ? Because "after every edit" seems to me like every type the user edit their input.